# SQL to get clients that do not belong to categories

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose my table is as follows,

```
id category
1   a
5   a
5   b
4   NULL
6   b
6   c
7   a
7   d
```

I want to get ids that do not belong to group "a" as a result

```
id category
4   NULL
6   b, c
```

What is the most elegant way to do this.
Now I use something like that, but my result is not exactly what I need. As this also gets ids 5 and 7

```
SELECT g.id, g.category
FROM groups g
WHERE (g.category<>'a' OR g.category IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from groups
where id not in (select id from groups where category = 'a')
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way probably uses `<=>`, MySQL's `NULL`-safe comparison operator.  So:

```
SELECT g.id, g.category
FROM groups g
WHERE NOT (g.category <=> 'a');
```

But your method is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could do EXIST

```
SELECT G.*
  FROM GROUPS G
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM GROUPS G2
            WHERE G2.category = 'a'
              AND G.id = G2.id
         )
```